# Error when attempting to modify Git config file in Windows

Tags: git

I am trying to modify the Git config file in Windows

```
git config --global user.name myname
```

but I get this error:

> error: could not lock config file (null)/(null)/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Comment: What does `set`output on cmd? I suppose %HOME% environment variable is not correctly set to your user directory.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374481/836169) to this related question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure your Environment Variables are correctly setup.

right-click on My Computer => Properties => Advanced => Environment Variables =>  System Variables

Find `HOME` variable and set it to `%USERPROFILE%`